# Is it possible to implement a heap without knowing the size of the input beforehand?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, heap

Say, I have a continuous input of integers of unknown size. At any instant in time, upon receiving k elements as input, I would like to have a heap of size k. How can this be achieved without initializing an array of some length beforehand?

Comment: java.util.ArrayList is re-allocating backing array as number of items grows.

Answer (score 1):

With binary tree based heap. You do not need to know the Limits on size.

http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/BinaryHeapImplementation.html

Even with array-based implementation, you can use the doubling of allocated size trick when capacity falls short. It will have same time complexity.

[Use ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

[why use ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2182651/3169556)

Answer (score 0):

The underlying data-structure of `java.util.PriorityQueue` is a heap. I assume by mentioning heap you meant to have ordering functionality on your data.

When you initialize a `PriorityQueue` using default constructor, it creates a `PriorityQueue` with the default initial capacity (11) that orders its elements according to their natural ordering. If you define a custom `Comparator`, it will order according to your constraint.

Other dynamic size data-structure like `ArrayList` won't provide the functionality of sorted order unless you sort them own-self.

I think you want to solve something similar to k'th smallest/largest element of a running stream. If yes, you can initialize `PriorityQueue` with default constructor and on pushing each element check if its current size is `k`. if it's current size is `k`, replace top element with new element according your constraint.

And last of all, use `ArrayList` if you only need dynamic size and don't need ordering like heap.